# SP List is not updated but updates can be seen through alert box CAML SPServices Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, spservices, update

I am trying to update my list. My codes already worked but I don't know what happened. When I designed my page, then hit Ctrl +S, then upload it again to share point, the codes didn't run already. I have deadline.

When I click table row, information goes to text box. When I change something in the tex tbox and clicked button, the table should update, but in my codes, it doesn't work.

Here's my code for SP Services: I don't know if I miss something or if I deleted something. I'll appreciate your answers. I hope for fast replies. Thanks a lot!

```
function Updatethis(){
    var method = "UpdateListItems";
    var list = "RFA_BODIList";
    var id=document.getElementById('ID').value;
    var supfunc=document.getElementById('supfunc').value;
    var tn=document.getElementById('tn').value;
    var td=document.getElementById('td').value;
    var ttype=document.getElementById('ttype').value;
    var prio=document.getElementById('prio').value;
    var func=document.getElementById('func').value;
    var req=document.getElementById('req').value;
    var rsum=document.getElementById('rsum').value;

    var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>" +
        "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='TicketNumber' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='TicketDescription' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='TicketType' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Priority' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='RequestorFunctionalArea' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Requestor' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='RequestSummary' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='RequestDate' />" +
        "<FieldRef Name='Status' />" +
        "</ViewFields>";

   var query = "<Query>" +
                    "<Where>" +
                            "<Eq>" +
                                "<FieldRef Name='ID'/><Value Type='Number'>" + id + "</Value>" +
                            "</Eq>" +
                    "</Where>" +
                "</Query>";

    $().SPServices({
            operation: method,
            async: false,
            listName: list,
            CAMLViewFields: fieldsToRead,
            CAMLQuery: query,
            updates: "<Batch OnError='Continue' PreCalc='TRUE'>" +
                        "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
                            "<Field Name='ID'>" + id + "</Field>" +
                            "<Field Name='Title'>" + supfunc + "</Field>" +
                            "<Field Name='TicketNumber'>" + tn + "</Field>" +
                            "<Field Name='TicketDescription'>" + td + "</Field>" +
                            "<Field Name='TicketType'>" + ttype + "</Field>" +
                            "<Field Name='Priority'>" + prio + "</Field>" +
                            "<Field Name='FunctionalArea'>" + func + "</Field>" +
                            "<Field Name='Requestor'>" + req + "</Field>" +
                            "<Field Name='RequestSummary'>" + rsum + "</Field>" +
                        "</Method>" +
                    "</Batch>",
            completefunc: function (xData, Status) {


            alert(updates);
            alert(id);
            alert(supfunc);
            alert(tn);
            alert(td);
            alert(ttype);
            alert(prio);
            alert(func);
            alert(req);



            //location.reload();
            }
   });
}
```

Here's my codes for text boxes and button:

```
 <div class="inputWrapper" style="margin-top: 40px;">
<input type="text" id="ID"/>
<input type="text" id="supfunc"/>
<input type="text" id="tn"/>
<input type="text" id="td"/>
<input type="text" id="ttype"/>
<input type="text" id="prio"/>
<input type="text" id="func"/>
<input type="text" id="req"/>
<input type="text" id="rsum"/>
```

`</div>
<input type="button" value="Update" class="Updatethis" onclick="Updatethis()"/>`

Answer (score 0):

I already figured it out.

If you can see:
The Name of my `<FieldRef Name = 'RequestorFunctionalArea'/>` here...(see below)

```
var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>" +
    "<FieldRef Name='ID' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='TicketNumber' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='TicketDescription' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='TicketType' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Priority' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='RequestorFunctionalArea' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Requestor' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='RequestSummary' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='RequestDate' />" +
    "<FieldRef Name='Status' />" +
    "</ViewFields>";
```

is different to my `"<Field Name='FunctionalArea'>" + func + "</Field>"`. See below.

```
 updates: "<Batch OnError='Continue' PreCalc='TRUE'>" +
                    "<Method ID='1' Cmd='Update'>" +
                        "<Field Name='ID'>" + id + "</Field>" +
                        "<Field Name='Title'>" + supfunc + "</Field>" +
                        "<Field Name='TicketNumber'>" + tn + "</Field>" +
                        "<Field Name='TicketDescription'>" + td + "</Field>" +
                        "<Field Name='TicketType'>" + ttype + "</Field>" +
                        "<Field Name='Priority'>" + prio + "</Field>" +
                        "<Field Name='FunctionalArea'>" + func + "</Field>" +
                        "<Field Name='Requestor'>" + req + "</Field>" +
                        "<Field Name='RequestSummary'>" + rsum + "</Field>" +
                    "</Method>" +
                "</Batch>",
```

Just change the Name, and tada! It will work!
They should have the same name. I just overlooked it.

I hope this will help others. Thank you for reading.

To God be the glory!